# Компоненты Vue js (родительские и дочерние)

Tags: vue.js

В документации не указано где наблюдать дочернего, а где родительского. Просто "как вы видите, родительским компонент передает данные вложенному". Напишите ,пожалуйста, пример родительских и вложенных компонентов.

```
Vue.component("my-component", {
    template: `<li> Hello </li>`
})

new Vue({
    el: "#app"
})

<div id="app">
    <my-component> </my-component>
</div>
```

В данном примере я вижу только один компонент без родительского и дочернего, это "my-component". Жду ответов, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Может так понятней станет:

```
Vue.component("my-component", {
    template: `<li> Hello </li>`
})

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    mounted(){
        console.log(this.$children); 
        // > [Vuecomponent] - массив дочерних компонентов
    }
})

<div id="app">
    <my-component> </my-component>
</div>
```